# Julia - How to know what is the latest version (v1.0.0) equivalent function?

Tags: julia

I previously used `ismatch` function in Julia v0.6.0 but now it returns an error with v1.0.0 and it's not present in the v0.7.0 or v1.0 documentation. So how can I find the non depreciated equivalent of `ismatch` for latest Julia version ?

More generally in Julia, how is it possible to know the equivalent of any depreciated function if it exists ?

I only have Julia v1.0 installed on my computer.

Comment: You may call the deprecated function *once* in v0.7. It should give you deprecation warning and ideally a solution.
In addition, you can instead look up [v0.7.0 Release Notes](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.7.0/NEWS/)  to find news about the deprecated functions. For example, `ismatch(regex, str)` has been deprecated in favor of `contains(str, regex)`. There is a catch though, `contains` has also been deprecated: "`contains` has been deprecated in favor of a more general `occursin` function, which takes its arguments in reverse order from `contains`."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to porting old v0.6 code to v1.0, it is generally recommended to use v0.7. Typically, it will show you a deprecation warning with instructions on how to get the same result in v1.0.

For example, we can run code involving `ismatch` as follows (on Julia v0.7):

```
julia> ismatch(r"a.c", "abc")
┌ Warning: `ismatch(r::Regex, s::AbstractString)` is deprecated, use `occursin(r, s)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at none:0
└ @ Core none:0
true
```

According to the deprecation warning, we should replace all calls to `ismatch(r::Regex, s::AbstractString)` with `occursin(r, s)` for future compatibility. In the case that deprecations occur throughout a project, Julia (v0.7) may be started using the `--depwarn=error` flag, which will immediately error (and provide detailed information about location) upon calling a deprecated method.

Note that deprecations are defined in [`base/deprecations.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/base/deprecated.jl#L1287). You can check this file on github or locally to see what function 0.7 is mapping the deprecated method to.

(Note that there is also a function `match` in v1.0, which one gets as a suggestion when doing `?ismatch` on 1.0.)

Comment: Thank you, that helped, however, the link in the original answer from @crstnbr [`deprecated.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/base/deprecated.jl#L1287) (click it!) was useful and I don't think it sould be edited

Comment: For reference, https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md lists most important changes between v0.6 and v0.7, most of which remain valid in v1.0 (has saved me several times!)